# How to get the current time in millisecond in Fortran?

Tags: time, fortran

I want to get the current system time in milliseconds in Fortran. I can't use `system_clock`, because I can't figure out how to get the current time from it.

Comment: You can't. [`system_clock`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM_005fCLOCK.html) gives you the *[...] processor clock since an unspecified time in the past [...]*. You can use the difference between two instances in time to "measure" runtime, though.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: [`date_and_time`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DATE_005fAND_005fTIME.html).

Comment: @VladimirF: Didn't your edit just change the question? `must` -> `can't`?

Comment: "I must work with system_clock because i cant figure it out" didn't make any sense, but who knows, maybe you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is: "how can I call **date_and_time** subroutin and access it to calculate ms?" Am I right?
Alexander's answer was true.also you can use this code:

```
  program time
  integer :: values(8)
  call date_and_time(values=values)
  print *, values(5),":",values(6),":",values(7),":",values(8)
  end program time
```

Answer (score 10):

This illustrates how to get the time since midnight in milliseconds using [`date_and_time`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DATE_005fAND_005fTIME.html):

```
program time
  integer :: values(8)
  real    :: rTime

  ! Get the values
  call date_and_time(values=values)

  ! From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DATE_005fAND_005fTIME.html
  ! values(5) ... The hour of the day
  ! values(6) ... The minutes of the hour
  ! values(7) ... The seconds of the minute
  ! values(8) ... The milliseconds of the second 

  ! Calculate time since midnight
  rTime = ( values(5) )*60.         ! Hours to minutes
  rTime = ( rTime + values(6) )*60. ! Minutes to seconds
  rTime = ( rTime + values(7) )*1e3 ! Seconds to milliseconds
  rTime = rTime + values(8)         ! Add milliseconds

  ! Time in seconds 
  print *, 'Time (ms) since midnight', rTime
end program
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ITIME()`, a function embedded in Fortran. It returns a real number in units of milliseconds. You just need to call it twice and subtract the two values in order to calculate the time interval.

Comment: `itime` is not a Fortran function.

Comment: The OP wants the current time. How does calling it twice help in this regard?